Accessing system Definition in sitecore Content Hub
Is there any way to access the M.File and M.PublicLink entities in Sitecore Content Hub?

Yes, you can access the M.File and M.PublicLink entities in Sitecore Content Hub using the Content Hub SDK or through direct API calls.
Here is how you can access these entities
// Get M.File entity
var fileEntity = await client.Entities.GetAsync("M.File", Entity ID); 

// Get M.PublicLink entity
var publicLinkEntity = await client.Entities.GetAsync("M.PublicLink", Entity ID); 


It is not possible to view these entities directly from the portal interface. However, you can access the M.File and M.PublicLink entities in Sitecore Content Hub using the Content Hub SDK, the REST API, or action scripts.
Or
As you cannot directly access the schema or entity links for these definations, you can use the following links in the URL for M.File and M.PublicLink respectively:

http://{CH-Instance}/en-us/admin/definitionmgmt/detail/38
https://{{CH-Instance}}/en-us/admin/definitionmgmt/detail/51

